# Combination of Mapview , phonegap and sancha touch

Tags: android, html, cordova

Is it possible to use android native MapView with the combination of Phonegap and Sancha Touch (for fancy UI)

Just like Zillow's new android version , in which they are using MapView to show locations and for screens they have used fancy UI

[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HDs9wAaK-8&feature=player_embedded#!)